# How to automate SQL queries with a txt file input?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to make a small script in order to automate the deletion of some rows in a table. Basically I would like a the script to read information from a txt file that contains the rows to be deleted and then they are automatically added to the query. For example the text file will have two columns,

```
0900209N    0910609S
0900210N    0910610S
```

and then these are added to the below code `and FLD_LOCATION_LABEL >= '0900210N' and FLD_LOCATION_LABEL <= '0910610S'`.

```
    select count(*),test_storage,TEST_PRIMARY
    from TEST_LOCATION
    where fld_location_num in (select fld_location_num
                       from test_location_coordinates                                         
                       where FLD_LOCATION_LABEL >= '0900209N' and FLD_LOCATION_LABEL <= '0910609S'
                          and FLD_LOCATION_LABEL >= '0900210N' and FLD_LOCATION_LABEL <= '0910610S')
    group by fld_storage_class_code,FLD_PRIMARY_STRG_CLASS_IND
    order by fld_storage_class_code;

    delete
```

So the resultant code is dependent on how many rows are in the text file.

Comment: how frequently is the list of files refreshed?  How many entries are in a typical list?  Are they always separated by a space or do they use a , or pipe |  ?

Comment: Are the example values in your text file supposed to be the basis for both the pairs of where clause conditions? They don't seem to match at the moment, which is confusing. (They are also mutually exclusive). What kind of script are you trying to write - SQL, shell, something else - and where/how will you run it? Where will this text file live - on the server (somewhere you could read it with utl_file) or on a separate client?

Comment: @kevinsky the text files are just reformatted from csv/excel, entries can range from a few rows to a couple dozen, the formatting can be modified as per whatever is easier (comma delimited etc). 
AlexPoole Sorry that they didn't match, I just fixed it. I'm executing commands from the UNIX terminal and would place the txt file directly on the server. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you

```
DECLARE
  fhandle UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  line    VARCHAR2(80);
  l_start varchar2(20);
  l_end varchar2(20);
  l_length number;
  l_cnt number;
  l_test_storage varchar2(20);
  l_test_primary varchar2(20);
BEGIN
  fhandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('TMP', 'myoutput', 'R');
  LOOP
    UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(fhandle, line);
    l_start := substr(line, 1, instr(line,' ')-1);
    l_end := substr(line,instr(line,' ')+1);
    select count(*),test_storage,TEST_PRIMARY into l_cnt,l_test_storage,l_test_primary
    from TEST_LOCATION
    where fld_location_num in (select fld_location_num
                       from test_location_coordinates                                         
                       where FLD_LOCATION_LABEL between l_start and l_end
                          )
    group by fld_storage_class_code,FLD_PRIMARY_STRG_CLASS_IND
    order by fld_storage_class_code;
    --delete statements if required  
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN
     dbms_output.put_line('Exception occured');
END;
```

Comment: You're assuming the file is on the server and can be read by the Oracle user, which I don't think is clear from the question. You're also running one query/delete per line in the file, not building up a single query/delete from all the contents of the file, though that may be acceptable. But you aren't selecting *into* anything so this isn't valid. (I'm not sure the OP really wants to see what will be deleted, but also unclear!)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that the values are not put into.Updated.when we are unaware of the size of the text file, deleting dynamically through a single script would not be feasible and hence put that in the loop. The purpose of what we are aiming for is met with the script .

Comment: Well, the range of values implies multiple results are expected, so you'd get too-many-rows. It is feasible to get all the ranges from the file and use them in a single select/delete, but there's not much point going into it until the OP clarifies what they need.

Comment: The file is on the server, and it would be nice to see whats being deleted. Single select/delete or one per line is not a big issue, and you are correct the values in the text file specify a range of values, basically beginning to end. I will try out this answer and update tomorrow hopefully. Thx